# error in file(con, "w")

Tags: r, powershell

This is windows 10 context.  R Script (as function) listens to some realtime data and then is supposed to play an audible alarm once some level is tripped.  The alarm is activated by a separate function call, and that function simply plays an mp3 file which I play via the following

```
command: system("powershell.exe", input="C:/Users/ThisUser/Music/Alarms/alarm_alarm_alarm2.mp3").
```

Additional background is that I'm typically running 3 (or more) other rstudio sessions on the machine.  This is the error:

```
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘httpuv’ was built under R version 3.4.1 
2: In file(con, "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp9w7SM3\file44982a915cf4': No such file or directory
```

I can test that system command from the console in another rstudio session and it works fine, but if I test in the console of the session where the error resides, I continue to get the error.  Also, when I check the tempdir this is what I get:

tempdir()
[1] "C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp9w7SM3"

Are my other sessions messing up the Temp files or directory path?  How can I fix?  Thank you.